# Remove all observation info for object on dealloc

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've been having trouble with this error:

> "An instance 0x156ad8d0 of class Actor was deallocated while key value
>   observers were still registered with it. Observation info was leaked,
>   and may even become mistakenly attached to some other object. Set a
>   breakpoint on NSKVODeallocateBreak to stop here in the debugger.
>   Here's the current observation info:"

Is there an efficient way to unregister all objects the receiver is observing, as well as unregistering all objects that are observing it? The only way I can find to unregister things is via removeObserverForKeyPath - and that would require me to keep track of all registered objects and keypaths, which could get cumbersome.

Comment: No magic function, just `removeObserverForKeyPath`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `removeObserverForKeyPath:` as @Kevin suggested.

*However*, you *really* should be removing the observers prior to deallocation.  During deallocation, the state of the instance will be inconsistent, most likely.   Especially when dealing with a class hierarchy.   Thus, having observers active during deallocation is often the source of some really wonky, hard to fix, bugs.